# Different behavior Field in pydantic and SQLModel in OpenAPI spec

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic, sqlmodel

To my knowledge, `SQLmodel` is partially based on `pydantic`. Nevertheless, I get a different resulting OpenAPI specification when using the `Field` function from `SQLmodel` in `FastAPI`.

For example, look at the following example:

```
from typing import Optional
from fastapi import FastAPI
from sqlmodel import Field, SQLModel

app = FastAPI()

class Model(SQLModel):
    nullable_param: Optional[int] = Field(None, nullable=True)

@app.get("/test", response_model=Model)
def foo():
    return Model(nullable_param=3)
```

This code runs and a `GET` on the `test` endpoint correctly returns `{"nullable_param":3}`. However, the resulting `OpenAPI` specification for `Model` is the following:

```
{
    "Model":{
        "title":"Model",
        "type":"object",
        "properties":{
            "nullable_param":{"title":"Nullable Param","type":"integer"}
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `nullable_param` lacks the `nullable=true` attribute!

When I import `Field` directly from `pydantic` (`from pydantic import Field`), it *does* include this attribute:

```
{
    "Model":{
        "title":"Model",
        "type":"object",
        "properties":{
             "nullable_param":{ "title":"Nullable Param", "type":"integer", "nullable":true }
        }
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is there perhaps a bug in the `Field` implementation of `SQLModel` in a `FastAPI` context?

pydantic 1.8.2
fastapi 0.74.1
sqlmodel 0.0.6
python 3.8.12